# UI issues for partial view rendering

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The below Ajax Action Link calls a Controller Action and returns the result within a partial view. The problem is as many times I click on the Action Link "Academic Details" it generates the result and div with partial view again. I want to prevent this.

Can you suggest any simple jQuery Tab view to solve this please. I've used one but it fires the controller for each click on link whether it works for the normal DIV.

```csharp
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Academic Details",
    "GetAcademicInfo",
    "Employee", new { empId = Model.Id },            
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AcademicDetails", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore },
    new { @id = "AcademicDetailsLink" }
)
```

Comment: Is the it the problem that every time you click the link it adds the contents of the partial view? So if you click the link several times you get repeated markup?

Comment: I did not get the last part _Can you suggest any simple jQuery Tab view to solve this please. I've used one but it fires the controller for each click on link whether it works for the normal DIV._

Comment: for repeated divs on click that can be solved

Comment: @Rui yup u r ryt. I've used a DIV to render the partial view in it.

Comment: @chaitanya firstly I think jQuery show/hide mechanism. But I have few more Action Links. And each Action Link DIV will be visible at own click and others DIV will be disappear. That's why I need to create a tab view by jQuery. Think u get me now.

Comment: @sharmoon I've updated my answer with an example of how you can achieve what you need with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to have a div with a particular id for each ajax link and use `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace`. For example

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Academic Details",
    "GetAcademicInfo",
    "Employee", new { empId = Model.Id },            
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AcademicDetails", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace},
    new { @id = "AcademicDetailsLink" }
)
<div id="AcademicDetails"></div>

@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Other Details",
    "GetOtherInfo",
    "Employee", new { empId = Model.Id },            
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "OtherDetailsDivId", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace},
    new { @id = "OtherDetailsLinkId" }
)
<div id="OtherDetailsDivId"></div>
```

If you want to show and hide on each click the other divs, here's how you do it with jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#AcademicDetailsLink').click(function(){
  $('#OtherDetailsDivId').hide();
  $('#AcademicDetails').show();
});

$('#OtherDetailsLinkId').click(function(){
  $('#OtherDetailsDivId').show();
  $('#AcademicDetails').hide();
});
</script>
```

You'll have to do this for each link.

Comment: u r correct. thnx for ur answer. But it wud be great if this script works dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Make the insertion mode to `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace`. This way each click will just replace that div again instead of adding same content on each click

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Academic Details",
    "GetAcademicInfo",
    "Employee", new { empId = Model.Id },
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AcademicDetails", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace },
    new { @id = "AcademicDetailsLink" }
)
```

Comment: yup using InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace can solve the problem. But I have few more Action Link. All I want to behave it like Tab view.